# check directory free space on windows using python

Tags: python, space

I have a task to check free space on particular directory on Windows. I figured out how to check for space of the drive. I was using ctypes module .
Could you please help me to figure out which module or function should I use to get similar information for directory on Windows?
Thanks

Comment: Unless the directory has a quota imposed on it externally or something, the free space in the directory is essentially the free space on the drive.

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't make a lot of sense. Directories don't have "free space". As long as there is free space on the drive, you can use as much of it in a directory as you want.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. My point that I care e.g. directory "Dir" located on drive "C:". Maybe it was my misconception. I assumed that directory could be 'full' while drive still have enouph space ... Looks that I was wrong. - Al Sweigart: did I understand correct that I should care only about available space on the drive where directory is located?